# QuTiP Python: Another version of PIL

Tags: python, installation, runtime, python-imaging-library

I try to install QuTip (http://qutip.org/docs/2.2.0/installation.html) on Windows using Python(x,y). After the installation I cannot import qutip

```
from qutip import *
```

it gives the error message

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:71: RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message when trying yo use PIL 2.3.0-6 coming with Python(x,y).
I had to upgrade to PIL 2.4.0